# How to create new project collection in TFS 2010 remotely

Tags: tfs

We have installed TFS 2010 RC.  By default it creates a project collection called DefaultCollection.  I would like to create a new project collection.  Using the TFS admin tool, team explorer or web interface I do not see a way to this.

There is a console on the server to do it but our network admins won't/can't give me direct access to the server (but I do have full TFS admin rights). Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Team Foundation Server 2010 has the great new Administration Console, however one of the shortcomings of it is that you have to run it on the TFS Application Tier itself. The team wants to have a tool that allows remote server administration, however it required more time than we had for this release."

He also shows a way to use Power Shell, see the link below.

Source: [granth's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/archive/2010/02/27/tfs2010-create-a-new-team-project-collection-from-powershell.aspx)